# Pipeline should accept input from user

Tags: terraform, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working looking for solution  where the azure pipeline should ask approval post execution of Plan task, i want control over very next task in my pipeline, if i put approve itshould prroceed and if i say deny it should not run below task.

basically a input based controlled condition .

```
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: Terraform Plan
        inputs:
          command: 'plan'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/manifests'
          commandOptions: '-out cluster.tfplan'
          allowTelemetryCollection: false


      - task: ManualValidation@0
        displayName: Terraform Plan Validation
        timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
        inputs:
          notifyUsers: |
            demo@gmail.com
          instructions: 'Please validate the Terraform Plan'
          onTimeout: 'reject'

      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: Terraform Apply
        inputs:
          command: 'apply'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/manifests'
          commandOptions: '-auto-approve cluster.tfplan'
```

i refered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

[image]

Comment: Are you running a selfhosted instance of ADO? The manual validation ask is only supported by [agentless jobs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321#agentless-tasks)

Comment: i am using microsoft hosted agent to run this job